# Tap gesture recognizer Not working for UIWebiew inside UIScrollView,which is inside UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios4

I've placed the WebView inside a Scrollview, which in turn is placed inside a view of the viewcontroller.
When tapping on the webview, "tapRecognized" method is not getting called.

Here's my code :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *oneFingerTwoTaps = 
      [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized)] autorelease];

    [oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];


// Add the gesture to the view

[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];
```

I've also tried  with the foll :

```
[scrollview addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];

[webview addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding the following statement:

```
//.h
...
@interface yourclass <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
...

//.m
...
[oneFingerTwoTaps setDelegate:self];
...

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

I hope it can help

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue, but again arises an another one.
Inside scrollview am having textField & button, when they are tapped I dont want this gesture to apply for them. Wt should I do for tht??

Comment: if you want your event to be triggered by only webview, add the webview TapRecognizer, thus should not interact with the button ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Gesture Recognizers can ONLY be added to a single view. Views cannot share a gesture recognizer. While UIViews can have multiple gesture recognizers attached a UIGestureRecognizer can only be attached a single view. Here is the property thats set on the UIGestureRecognizer when you addGesture to any UIView based view.

```
view
The view the gesture recognizer is attached to. (read-only)

@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view

Discussion
 You attach (or add) a gesture recognizer to a UIView object using the addGestureRecognizer: method.

Availability
 Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared In
 UIGestureRecognizer.h
```